# Deserializing json with Nodatime results in null values

Tags: json, nodatime

I have a Controller returning an object with a Nodatime `Period` property `Interval`:

```json
// Formatted
{
    "id": "5d6c4def-26e1-4045-b34a-70f75e992be4",
    "code": "code",
    "name": "name",
    "toleranceBefore": 14,
    "toleranceAfter": 14,
    "interval": "P90D"
}

// Raw string from ReadAsStringAsync()
"{\"id\":\"5d6c4def-26e1-4045-b34a-70f75e992be4\",\"code\":\"code\",\"name\":\"name\",\"toleranceBefore\":14,\"toleranceAfter\":14,\"interval\":\"P90D\"}"
```

I am trying to read and parse the json like this using the nodatime jsonconfig:

```cs
var result = getResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyContract>(
                new JsonSerializerOptions()
                    .ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
```

It results in an object where all values are default values (Guid.Empty, string.Empty, 0...). If I try to read without the nodatime options, I get the same default values respoonse.

```json
{
    "id": "000...", // simplified for brevity
    "code": "",
    "name": "",
    "toleranceBefore": 0,
    "toleranceAfter": 0,
    "interval": ""
}
```

When reading with Newtonsoft (without specific nodetime jsonconfig) the response is parsed and I get the P90D as a string value and all other values are set as expected with their non-default values.

```cs
var rawString = await getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyContract>(rawString);
```

My Controllers are configured:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
```

Setting a breakpoint in the Controller where the `Ok(my object)` is executed show the object as it should be (with the non-default values). Which of course is confirmed by the raw json string.

What am I doing wrong when trying to read the json using the default `System.Text` json deserializer?

Small test example:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test1()
{
    var s =
        "{\"id\":\"5d6c4def-26e1-4045-b34a-70f75e992be4\",\"code\":\"code\",\"name\":\"name\",\"toleranceBefore\":14,\"toleranceAfter\":14,\"interval\":\"P90D\"}";

    var newton = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyContract>(s);
    var system = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MyContract>(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)));
    var systemWithOpts =
        await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<MyContract>(
            new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)),
            options:new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));

    Assert.True(true);
}

public class MyContract
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ToleranceBefore { get; set; }
    public long ToleranceAfter { get; set; }
    public Period Interval { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I *suspect* this has nothing to do with Noda Time, and everything to do with capitalization - System.Text.Json is case-sensitive by default. Have you tried annotating your `MyContract` class properties with `JsonPropertyName`? (At the very least, I'd try removing the Noda Time configuration and the `Interval` property... if that still displays the same issue, which I expect it to, then clearly the problem has nothing to do with Noda Time...)

Comment: Any updates on this? (I'd prefer to remove the nodatime tag from this question unless it's really related to Noda Time.)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Noda Time and everything to do with the JSON and your class not matching in case. While Newtonsoft.Json is case-insensitive by default, System.Text.Json is case-sensitive by default. You'd see the same behavior without Noda Time being involved at all.

I suggest you use the `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute to tell System.Text.Json the expected JSON property name for each .NET property.

Complete sample:

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
{
    'id':'5d6c4def-26e1-4045-b34a-70f75e992be4',
    'code':'code',
    'name':'name',
    'toleranceBefore':14,
    'toleranceAfter':14,
    'interval':'P90D'
}".Replace("'", "\"");

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        var contract = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Contract>(json, options);

        Console.WriteLine($"ID: {contract.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Interval: {contract.Interval}");
    }
}

class Contract
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("toleranceBefore")]
    public long ToleranceBefore { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("toleranceAfter")]
    public long ToleranceAfter { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("interval")]
    public Period Interval { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to use the [Web-defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializerdefaults) for the options: `new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)`

Comment: @Johnbot: Indeed, although personally I generally favour being explicit about the JSON property names for clarity. You could definitely add that in a new answer.